# Mongoose toJSON {virtuals: true} is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get my make my virtual available when an array of document is returned so here is my schema

```
const photoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   
    isPublic: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    license: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['None', 'Public Domain Work', 'Public Domain Dedication'],
        default: 'None'
    },
    safety: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Safe', 'Moderate', 'Restricted'],
        default: 'Safe'
    },
    contentType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Screenshot', 'Art/Illustration', 'Photo'],
        required: true
    },
    creator: {
        type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    allowCommenting: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    toJSON: {
        virtuals: true
    },
    toObject: {
        virtuals: true
    }
})
//virtuals
photoSchema.virtual('favoured', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'favourites'
})
const Photo = mongoose.model('Photo', photoSchema)

module.exports = Photo
```

I have a user model which has an array of photos.id that he has favouried when I try in the code to populate the virtual it works fine. But in my endpoint I thought the problem might be that I have an array of documents so I tried explicit logging an Item in the array and invoking toJSON but it didn't work

```
const photos = await Photo.find({
        _id: { $in: favouritesArray },
    });
    console.log(photos[0].toJSON({virtuals: true}))
    res.send(photos);
```